# Grabbing names and IDs from another controller for a select menu in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Ruby Version: 2.0**

**Rails Version: 4.0**

I may be over complicating this, but I have 2 controllers - `Resident` and `Guest`

**resident.rb**

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :guests
end
```

**guest.rb**

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :resident
end
```

**guest migration**

```
class CreateGuests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :guests do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :phone_number
      t.integer :resident_id
      t.belongs_to :resident

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What I would like to do is allow the user to select a `Resident` that the `Guest` belongs to when creating a new `Guest` using a select menu. However, I am not sure how to pass the `resident.id` as the value, and the `resident.name` as what is displayed without doing a lot of ugly, manual work. How can I achieve this? here is my current - obviously not working - code.

**snippet from guests_controller.rb**

```
# GET /guests/new
def new
  @guest = Guest.new
  @residents = Resident.all
end
```

**/views/guests/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@guest) do |f| %>    
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone_number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :resident_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :resident_id, @residents,
          prompt: "select a resident" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Update: Problem solved**

Tyler and Jason were both half correct, but I gave Tyler the "accepted answer because he was closer.

I ended up solving my issue with this line in the controller:

`@residents = Resident.all.map { |resident| [resident.name, resident.id] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@residents = Resident.all.collect {|r| [ r.name, r.id ] }`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is right, but you can try this:

```
<%= f.select :resident_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@residents, :id, :name) %>
```

Documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html